# How to write a code for more than one file in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I wrote a script in AWK called exc7
`./exc7 file1 file2`
In every file there is a matrix

```
file1 :
2 6 7
10 5 4
3 8 4
file2:
-60 10
10   -60
```

The code that I wrote is :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
A[NR,i]=$i
}
END{
for (i=1;i<=NR;i++){
sum += A[i,1]
}
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
sum2 += A[1,i]
for (i=0;i<=NF;i++)
sum3 += A[NR,i]
for (i=0;i<=NR;i++)
sum4 += A[i,NF]
print sum,sum2,sum3,sum4
if (sum==sum2 && sum==sum3 && sum==sum4) 
print "yes"
}
```

It should check for every file if the sum of the first column and the last and the first line and the last is the same. It will print the four sum and say yes if they are equal.Then it should print the largest sum of all number in all the files.
when I try it on one file it is right like when I try it on file1 it prints:

```
15 15 15 15
yes
```

but when I try it on two or more files like file1 file 2 the output is :

```
-35 8 -50 -31
```

Comment: awk handles all file you enter as a single, combined file. So this gives just one result (because it's like awk only sees one file).

Comment: What can we do to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `FNR` instead of `NR` and with `gawk` you can use `ENDFILE` instead of `END`.  However, this should work with any `awk`

```
awk 'function sumline(last,rn) {n=split(last,lr); 
                                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) rn+=lr[i]; 
                                return rn}
     function printresult(c1,r1,rn,cn) {print c1,r1,rn,cn; 
                                        print (r1==rn && c1==cn && r1==c1)?"yes":"no"}

     FNR==1{if(last)
               {rn=sumline(last);
                printresult(c1,r1,rn,cn)}
            rn=cn=c1=0;
            r1=sumline($0)}
           {c1+=$1;cn+=$NF;last=$0}
     END   {rn=sumline(last);
            printresult(c1,r1,rn,cn)}' file1 file2

15 15 15 15
yes
-50 -50 -50 -50
yes
```

essentially, instead of checking end of file, you can check start of the file and print out the previous file's results.  Need to treat first file differently. You still need the `END` block to handle the last file.

**UPDATE**

Based on the questions you asked, I think it's better for you to keep your script as is and change the way you call it.

```
for file in file1 file2; 
    do echo "$file"; ./exc7 "$file";       
    done
```

you'll be calling the script once for each file, so all the complications will go away.

Comment: what does lr mean? Can you explain to me what every line does in this code?

Comment: it's just a dummy array to hold the values of the fields after `split`.  It's doing the same thing as summing all the values on a line, which is in your code as well.  The rest should be trivial.  I tried to explain the reasoning, there may be different implementations but the logic should follow what I mentioned.

Comment: and what last does?  and if i also wanted to write the file name before yes/no what should I do?

Comment: "last" refers to the last line (prior to current line).  It's only used starting the new file for the `rn` (row n) variable.  add `print FILENAME` statement to print the filename. In the `END` block you can replace "last" with `$0` but kept it for consistency.